# Save and add field in drupal doesn't exits

Tags: drupal

Recently "Save content type and add field" in Drupal has been faded. What's the problem? 
Here is screen shot! 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4KvY.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed Field UI module and cleared All cashe.

Answer (score 0):

**Save content type and add field** Only shows when you are creating a new content-type,

I think you are trying to edit the content-type so this is appearing as **Delete Content-type**.

Comment: When I create new content type, that problem occures.

Comment: which version of drupal is this ? I suspect, this might be disabled by other module or you can try changing theme and check if it persists.

Comment: Drupal 7, yes recently i've installed many modules.But which module disable it?